# how to use relations to check if value exists in an array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to use laravel relations to fetch a value.

I have declared some constants in a model `Skill` and trying to return if the id exists in the array of those constants or not. here is what I have

```
class Skill extends Model {
   CONST LEVEL_BEGINNER              =  1;
   CONST LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE          =  2;
   CONST LEVEL_EXPERIENCED           =  3;
   CONST LEVEL_EXPERT                =  4;
   public static function getLevels () {

        return [
            self::LEVEL_BEGINNER         => "Beginner",
            self::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE     => "Intermediate",
            self::LEVEL_EXPERIENCED      => "Experienced",
            self::LEVEL_EXPERT           => "Expert",
        ];

    }
    public function experience_level () {

        return self::getLevels()[$this->experience_level_id] ?? "";

    }
}
```

But, when I do this in controller

$skill->experience_level

it says

> App\Skill::experience_level must return a relationship instance.

How can I use this or is there any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using normal OOP functionality here, has nothing to do with the Laravel relationship. So in order to call your `experience_level()` function, just use:

```
$skill->experience_level()
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I know I'm using the normal OOP, and I know I can use it like that but I'm trying to see if there is a way to use it as a relation! I'll wait for answers before accepting.